# Different results after input - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I type in input `coup`, `cou`, and then `coup`, the results are different. Does anyone know what could be the reason for this?

Here's the jsfiddle for my code: [jsfiddle.net/xbuppd1r/43](http://jsfiddle.net/xbuppd1r/43)

```
var data = {"cards":[{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+SimpleData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","Id":89,"Name":"anathar","CardType":0,"CostAP":7,"Life":7,"Attack":4,"MovementPoint":2,"Families":[70],"IsToken":false,"Rarity":3,"GodType":0,"Extension":1,"LinkedCards":[],"Texts":{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+TextData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","NameFR":"Anathar","DescFR":"<b>CONTRE COUP :</b>\nTant qu'il est en vie, Anathar prend le contrôle de son adversaire.","NameEN":"Anathar","DescEN":"<b>COUNTERATTACK:</b>\nSo long as he is alive, Anathar takes control of his opponent.","NameES":"Anathar","DescES":"<b>VENGANZA:</b>\nMientras esté vivo, Anathar toma el control de su contrincante."}},{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+SimpleData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","Id":137,"Name":"appel_a_la_baston","CardType":1,"CostAP":7,"Life":0,"Attack":0,"MovementPoint":0,"Families":[1],"IsToken":false,"Rarity":3,"GodType":1,"Extension":1,"LinkedCards":[],"Texts":{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+TextData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","NameFR":"Appel à la Baston","DescFR":"Piochez portée 4 cartes.\r\nGardez les invocations et défaussez les autres.","NameEN":"Call to Brawl","DescEN":"Draw 4 cards.\r\nKeep the Summons and discard any others.","NameES":"Toque de Refriega","DescES":"Robas 4 cartas.\r\nConservas las invocaciones y descartas las otras."}},{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+SimpleData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","Id":20,"Name":"sphincter_cell","CardType":0,"CostAP":5,"Life":4,"Attack":4,"MovementPoint":3,"Families":[19],"IsToken":false,"Rarity":2,"GodType":0,"Extension":1,"LinkedCards":[],"Texts":{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+TextData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","NameFR":"Sphincter Cell","DescFR":"<b>COUP DE GRÂCE :</b>\nRécupérez le dernier Rat parti dans votre défausse.\r","NameEN":"Sphincter Cell","DescEN":"<b>FINAL BLOW:</b>\nRetrieve the last Rat that went to your discard pile.\n","NameES":"Sfinter Cell","DescES":"<b>GOLPE DE GRACIA:</b>\nRecuperas la última rata enviada a tu descarte.\n"}    },{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+SimpleData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","Id":20,"Name":"sphincter_cell","CardType":0,"CostAP":5,"Life":4,"Attack":4,"MovementPoint":3,"Families":[19],"IsToken":false,"Rarity":2,"GodType":0,"Extension":1,"LinkedCards":[],"Texts":{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+TextData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","NameFR":"Sphincter Cell","DescFR":"<b>COUP DE GRÂCE :</b>\nRécupérez le dernier Rat parti dans votre défausse.\r","NameEN":"Sphincter Cell","DescEN":"<b>FINAL BLOW:</b>\nRetrieve the last Rat that went to your discard pile.\n","NameES":"Sfinter Cell","DescES":"<b>GOLPE DE GRACIA:</b>\nRecuperas la última rata enviada a tu descarte.\n"}    },{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+SimpleData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","Id":20,"Name":"sphincter_cell","CardType":0,"CostAP":5,"Life":4,"Attack":4,"MovementPoint":3,"Families":[19],"IsToken":false,"Rarity":2,"GodType":0,"Extension":1,"LinkedCards":[],"Texts":{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+TextData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","NameFR":"Sphincter Cell","DescFR":"<b>COUP DE GRÂCE :</b>\nRécupérez le dernier Rat parti dans votre défausse.\r","NameEN":"Sphincter Cell","DescEN":"<b>FINAL BLOW:</b>\nRetrieve the last Rat that went to your discard pile.\n","NameES":"Sfinter Cell","DescES":"<b>GOLPE DE GRACIA:</b>\nRecuperas la última rata enviada a tu descarte.\n"}    },{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+SimpleData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","Id":20,"Name":"sphincter_cell","CardType":0,"CostAP":5,"Life":4,"Attack":4,"MovementPoint":3,"Families":[19],"IsToken":false,"Rarity":2,"GodType":0,"Extension":1,"LinkedCards":[],"Texts":{"$type":"Assets.Code.Editor.Helpers.SimpleCardDataExporter+TextData, Assembly-CSharp-Editor","NameFR":"Sphincter Cell","DescFR":"<b>COUP DE GRÂCE :</b>\nRécupérez le dernier Rat parti dans votre défausse.\r","NameEN":"Sphincter Cell","DescEN":"<b>FINAL BLOW:</b>\nRetrieve the last Rat that went to your discard pile.\n","NameES":"Sfinter Cell","DescES":"<b>GOLPE DE GRACIA:</b>\nRecuperas la última rata enviada a tu descarte.\n"}    }]}

$("#search").keyup(function(){
    // Minimally, you need to reset the results array here.
    results = [];

    var InputVal = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(InputVal, "i");

    if(InputVal.length > 0) {
        var results = data.cards.filter(function(obj){
            for(var key in obj)
                if ( String( obj.Texts.DescFR ).toLowerCase().match(myExp))  return true;
                if ( String( obj.Name ).toLowerCase().match(myExp) ) return true;

        return false;
    });

var newHTML = [];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    newHTML.push(results[i].Name);          
}   

console.log(JSON.stringify(newHTML));
// our variable holding starting index of this "page"
var index = 0;

// display our initial list
displayNext();

$("#next").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

      // display next elements
      displayNext();
});


function displayNext() {
    // get the list element
    var list = $('#list');

    // get index stored as a data on the list, if it doesn't exist then assign 0
    var index = list.data('index') % newHTML.length || 0;

    // save next index - for next call
    list.data('index', index + 16);

    // 1) get 20 elements from array - starting from index, using Array.slice()
    // 2) map them to array of li strings
    // 3) join the array into a single string and set it as a HTML content of list

    list.html($.map(newHTML.slice(index, index + 16), function(val){
        console.log(val);
        return '<div class="col-md-2">' + val + '</div>';
        }).join(''));
    }   
}
});
```

I don't know why it produces different results when I type in my entry, it's very strange.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I provided an answer that straightforwardly solves the issue (I tested it), and got a downvote with no explanation. Evidently the question was not posted to try and find a helpful suggestion or identification of the problem. The user probably just wants you to write out the complete implementation. That's what paid consultants are for.

Answer (score 0):

Your results array isn't getting refreshed whenever you enter a new search.

I noticed that the second time you enter "coup", you get the same results as originally entering "co".

I added this line inside your keyup event, and now whenever I type "coup", I get the same result. Your final implementation will involve making sure that for each new search, you either refresh this array, or remove results from it that are no longer valid whenever the input changes (so, on keyup in your case).

```
results = [];
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote, you should say why. For the record I actually implemented your code and this fixed it. This sort of thing really demotivates people from trying to help.

Comment: When I add results = []; That does not change my script. When I erase or retype the same thing, the result is not the same !